# Python class override

Tags: python, django, class, overriding

I am trying to override the Media class in the Django OpenLayersWidget

Here is my code:

```
class OpenLayersWidgetHttps(OpenLayersWidget):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js',
            'gis/js/OLMapWidget.js',
        )
```

However, when I try:

```
w = OpenLayersWidgetHttps()
print(w.media)
```

I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.13/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/gis/js/OLMapWidget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

Somehow, the default media entry of `'http://openlayers.org/api/2.13/OpenLayers.js'` is being kept.

**Why is this not properly overriding the value of `js`?**

For reference, here is the definition of OpenLayersWidget in the Django source:

```
class OpenLayersWidget(BaseGeometryWidget):
    template_name = 'gis/openlayers.html'

    class Media:
        js = (
            'http://openlayers.org/api/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js',
            'gis/js/OLMapWidget.js',
        )
```

Comment: I looked into the code and the media always returns a list with openlayers url. It is visible here, for example: https://github.com/django/django/blob/dbb0df2a0ec5bee80bee336fc81408efb30b7e47/django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py#L47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/media/#extend) says:

> By default, any object using a static Media definition will inherit all the assets associated with the parent widget. This occurs regardless of how the parent defines its own requirements. For example, if we were to extend our basic Calendar widget from the example above:

You can set `extend = False` inside Media class to generate `media` variable without inherited values.

```
class OpenLayersWidgetHttps(OpenLayersWidget):
    class Media:
        extend = False
        js = (
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js',
            'gis/js/OLMapWidget.js',
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. This both explains the observed behavior and provides the correct workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of the _media(self) which gets the media property:

```
def _media(self):
    # Get the media property of the superclass, if it exists
    sup_cls = super(cls, self)
    try:
        base = sup_cls.media
    except AttributeError:
        base = Media()

    # Get the media definition for this class
    definition = getattr(cls, 'Media', None)
    if definition:
        extend = getattr(definition, 'extend', True)
        if extend:
            if extend is True:
                m = base
            else:
                m = Media()
                for medium in extend:
                    m = m + base[medium]
            return m + Media(definition)
        else:
            return Media(definition)
    else:
        return base
```

Basically, when you call [your class].media, the list of the superclasses entries are added to the resulting list. In other words, its doing what its supposed to.